# drop shadow effect for text in iOS4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been trying to get the following effects on my text:

[image]

I want to get the white border around my text, I tried playing around with the following, but it didn't work out

```
self.name.layer.shadowOpacity = 5.0;   
    self.name.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
    self.name.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.name.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -5.0);
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
self.name.layer.shadowColor = [label.textColor CGColor];
self.name.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
self.name.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
self.name.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0;
```

Comment: The proble with using a shadow is that it's not 100% solid.

Comment: are you sure this works? as I just see my old plain black text when I tried this